Google Oauth verification accepted but users are still blocked
I recently got my application Oauth verified, however when a user tries to authenticate they are blocked by a 403-access_denied error with the message: Access blocked: {org} has not completed the Google verification process
and in the error details:
Request details: access_type=offline response_type=code redirect_uri=storagerelay://https/{url}?id={auth_id} prompt=consent client_id={client_id} include_granted_scopes=true gsiwebsdk=3 enable_serial_consent=true scope=openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
These are the scopes the app was approved for:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
openid

All the sensitive scopes have been verified, and we have no restricted scopes
Google scope verification status
I would appreciate any help for how to solve this. Am I missing something in the error messages and accepted scopes? Are there additional pages in the google console that I should look?
I had hoped verification would solve the issue; however it still persists. I've contacted the Google api verification team and they informed this is not a verification issue and to direct my question elsewhere (specifically mentioning stackoverflow)
